# for loop only displays last value of iterations

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am using a for loop function in Matlab to display my values in a row like this

`[4;0;5;0;6;0;7;0;8;0;9;0;3;0;6];`

, but by using this code:

```
A = [4;5;6;7;8;9;3;6];
B = zeros;
C=height(A);
D=15;
for l = 1:2:D
    for k = 1:C
        B(l,1)=A(k,1);
    end
end
```

only the last values are displayed in the row, like this:

`[6;0;6;0;6;0;6;0;6;0;6;0;6;0;6]`

For the sake of this example I am using only integers but the real equation is much more complicated and I think I really need to use the loop function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you simply want to insert zeros between each value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

```
for l = 1:2:D
    for k = 1:C
        B(l,1)=A(k,1);
```

you are writing a value to the `l`-th entry of vector `B` and then overwriting that entry `C-1` times with other values (the last of which being `A(end)`). The main issue with your approach is that you don't need two loops as there are no orthogonal dimensions to be traversed; you could use instead:

```
A = [4;5;6;7;8;9;3;6];
C = size(A,1);
B = zeros( 2*C-1, 1 );
for l=1:C
    B( 2*l-1, 1 )=A(l,1);
end
```

where the `for` loop may be dropped altogether in favor of a vectorized operation:

```
B(1:2:end,1) = A(:,1);
```

If you have the Signal Processing Toolbox installed, you could alternatively use the [`upsample()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/upsample.html) function, especially if leading or trailing zeros in the result are not a problem.